# Java clipboard not updating during Robot execution

Tags: java, clipboard, updating, awtrobot

I am trying to do an application that copy a website text. The problem is that I cannot get clipboard updates, I have the following code:

```
           // Ctrl+A > right click > click on copy

            Clipboard cb = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
            StringSelection data = new StringSelection("https://www.discogs.com/");
            cb.setContents(data, data);
            Robot robo = new Robot();  
            robo.delay(500);
            robo.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
            robo.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
            robo.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);
            robo.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);

            robo.mouseMove(136, 874); 
            robo.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON3_MASK);
            robo.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON3_MASK);
            robo.delay(500);

            robo.mouseMove(323, 890);
            robo.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
            robo.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
            robo.delay(5000);

            //Run to update the clipboard
            new Thread(t1).start();
```

... so far, so good.

```
private static Runnable t1 = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try{

            Thread.sleep(500);

            Clipboard c = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
            String paste = c.getContents(null).getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor).toString();
            System.out.println(paste);

            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (Exception e){
        }
    }
};
```

What happens is that it does select and copy as I want, the clipboard in java execution is always "https://www.discogs.com/", if I ctrl+V on a notepad after the execution, it is the website content I want, I already triyed debuggin step by step, no Thread, CRTL+C insted of right click and copy, increasing and adding robo.delay and I cannot get the actual Windows clipboard, always the same result.

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: You are copying a string to the system clipboard. Do you think that pasting that string will cause the content of the Web page to be downloaded to your computer?

Comment: No, The string I pass is just to enter the website, it works, I want after the right click and copy to be able to read that on java, but I always get the old website I passed before, not the copyed content. Already triyed cleaning the clipboard before copying too, it stays null.  Thanks.

Comment: So, figured out that the problem is when the   cb.setContents(data, data); is given, the java can't read my  new clipboard entries anymore, it always stays as set, no matter if I override it in system, java shows me as setted before... Any one can help?